# How can I interpolate values into a string based on a key token using Parsec (Haskell)?

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm new to the world of parsing, and have a fairly simple-seeming problem:

I have a long string comprised of `Chunk`s of normal text, and `Key`s that are encoded like `<<key-label>>`.

```
data Merge a = Chunk a
             | Key a
  deriving (Show)

key :: Parser (Merge String)
key = Key <$> between (string "<<") (string ">>") (many1 letter)

chunk :: Parser (Merge String)
chunk = Chunk <$> many1 anyChar

prose = many1 $ key <|> chunk

ex = parseTest prose "hi <<x>> ! Do you like <<y>>?"

-- Returns: 
-- [Chunk "hi <<x>> ! Do you like <<y>>?"]

-- I'd like:
-- [Chunk "hi ", Key "x", Chunk " !", ...]
```

I'd like to replace those keys with values, but I can solve that if I can  parse a string into my tokens, IE `String -> [Merge]`.

I've dived into the boundless depths that is lexing/parsing, and while I hope to learn all of it eventually, any guidance on solving this problem now?

This is the simplest instantiation of my attempts, although I have tried separate passes over the data, including separate lexing/parsing steps, and I'd *like* to use `parsec` instead of a more concrete interpolation lib.

Comment: The moment your parser looks for a `Chunk`, it is going to slurp up all remaining characters, since its rule is `many1 anyChar`.  You will need to change the rule to disallow the sequence `<<`, which is the start of a `Key`.  However, if while parsing a `Key`, you encounter something other than a letter before seeing the `>>`, you have to decide if that's an error or if you want to back-track and just treat it as another `Chunk`.

Comment: @pat I understand how that `many1 anyChar` is too greedy, but, correct me if I'm wrong, wouldn't it be weird for `Chunk` to need to encode a concept of `Key`'s syntax (IE stop on `<<`)?

Comment: @Josh.F It depends on your desired semantics. Is `"<<"` a valid string? How about `"<< << >>"` or `"<< foo"`? Regardless, separate parsing/lexing steps are the way to go here (in reality, this simple example consists only of lexing and a little bit of cleanup on the result; if this isn't a vastly oversimplified version of what you're trying to do, forgo a parser altogether). Lexing should produce something like `[Tok "hi", OpenBrace, Tok "x", CloseBrace, ...]` after which the 'parsing' step is entirely trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `notFollowedBy` to say that you want a chunk to include a
character as long as it isn't a key.  `notFollowedBy` doesn't consume
input so `prose` will still go on to parse the key again as its own item.

```
chunk = Chunk <$> many1 (notFollowedBy key >> anyChar)
```

This will allow even things like `aaa<<bbbbbb` to be parsed as a chunk,
by going all the way to the end of the file, not finding a closing
`>>`, deciding that it must not have been a key and therefore it can
be part of the chunk.

If you would rather have `<<` always be the start of a key and fail if
it isn't closed, disallow `<<` from the chunk:

```
chunk = Chunk <$> many1 (notFollowedBy (string "<<") >> anyChar)
```

Comment: works! hey also, I know for more involved parsing, things that look ahead or backtrack are inefficient, and obviated by doing multiple passes. I've tried multiple pass approaches, but then I haven't been able to figure out how to use Parsec on tokens, instead of chars/strings. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

[replace-megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/)
is a library for doing search-and-replace with parsers. The
search-and-replace function is
[`streamEdit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:streamEdit).

```hs
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Data.Char

key = between (string "<<") (string ">>") (many letterChar) :: Parsec Void String String
editor k = "Key " ++ (fmap toUpper k)

streamEdit key editor "hi <<x>> ! Do you like <<y>>?"
```

```hs
"hi Key X ! Do you like Key Y?"
```

You can also get the intermediate separated strings with the
[`sepCap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec/docs/Replace-Megaparsec.html#v:sepCap)
parser combinator, which returns a structure equivalent to the `[Merge]`
that you were trying to build.